# SSIS package wrote 0 rows

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012

Yes, I read the other questions on the same topic, but they do not cover my issue.

We run two environments; DEV and Prod. The two were synched last week, meaning they ought to contain the same data, run the same SSIS packages, and source the same source data.

However, today we had a package on PROD go through its' usual steps (3 tables being truncated, and then loaded from OLEDB source to OLEDB destination, one after the other). The package finished without throwing an error, and the first 2 tables contain data, whereas the last one does not.

On DEV, everything looks fine.

I went through the package history, and it actually shows it wrote 0 rows:

[image]

Yesterday, however, it worked as intended:

[image]

When I manually ran the package, it wrote data. When I click "Preview", it displays data. When I manually run the source query, it consistently returns data, the same amount of rows, every time. The SSIS catalog has not been updated (no changes were deployed to PROD between yesterday and today).

The source query does not use table variables, but it does use CTEs. I have seen suggestions to add `SET NOCOUNT ON`, and willing to accept this could be an explanation. However, those answers seem to indicate the package never writes any data, whereas this package has worked successfully before, and works successfully on DEV.

Does anyone have any explanation as to how I can explain to my customer that I have no clue as to why 1 package suddenly chose not to write any data, and how I can ensure this won't happen again, to either this package or any of the other packages?

Comment: Did you check if the source of your data changed in the time you executed the production DTS (yielding 0 results for your query) and then went to a state that returned results afterwards?

Comment: I suggest you profile the source database at the time the query is run. You'll probably find some unexpected filtering is ocurring

Comment: @EzequielLópezPetrucci - We have a staging process running first, and source from there. By the time this particular package is kicked off, no changes are occurring in the staging tables anymore.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid There shouldn't be any filtering happening, other than what we add in the source of the package/component. That's the query I ran manually, and which produced a consistent resultset.

Comment: When you profile the SQL it might all become clearer. For example you might find it’s being run in the wrong database or something

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I can certainly try. However, then it'd also be run in the wrong database all other days, where it actually worked fine. But I'll give things a shot tomorrow morning :)

Comment: The other place to check is in the execution itself. The preview could be pointing to a stable source but the run-time execution changes the connection to point to an empty source

Comment: @billinkc I executed the package manually, using the regular production parameters, and this time it wrote the correct data. All other tables in the package use the same variables (except destination table name), and all got handled correctly. I've worked with SSIS for 10 years, and never seen anything like this, lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the issue was caused by an oversight.

Because we run DEV and PROD on the same server (we know, and have recommended the customer to at the very least consider using different instances)), we use variables in which we point at the proper environment (set in the environment variables).

The query feeding this particular package was updated, and apparently rather than using the variable to switch databases, it was hard-coded (likely as result of testing, and then forgetting to update the variable). The load for DEV and PROD run at the same time, and we suspect that while PROD was ready, DEV was still processing the source tables, and thus 0 rows were returned.

We only found this out today because the load again ran fine right until this morning. I was too late to catch it using Profiler, but because it was only this package, I checked, and spotted the hardcoded reference to _DEV.

Thanks everyone for chiming in.

Comment: Glad you got it !

Answer (score 1):

This can be tricky. Try the following:

1. Under `Integration Service Catalogs -> SSISDB -> project -> (right click)Reports -> Standard Reports -> All executions`. Check here if at any point, ETL job lost contact with warehouse.

2.If you have logging enabled, try to see at what task_name your package started returning 0:

```
select 
    data_stats_id,
    execution_id,
    package_name,
    task_name,
    source_component_name,
    destination_component_name,
    rows_sent
from 
    ssisdb.catalog.execution_data_statistics
```

3. How are you handling transactions and checkpoints? This is important if you want to know root cause of this issue. It may happen that due to loss of connectivity had forced to rollback any write in warehouse.

Comment: Thanks for this. All subsequent packages work as intended. It's literally this 1 task in this 1 package that for this 1 day decided to not write any rows. There's no transactions or checkpoints in the SSIS packages either.A simple select statement, with a derived column, and then pushing the result to a destination.